# PHP textarea validation for php editor

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to build an online php editor but I need to validate the users input before it gets submitted some that my system doesnt return php errors back to the user.

I'm quite new to php some im sure on what type of validation to use. I would like to check that the first line of text has ""

I'd also like to check for things like if the users enters one " then they close it with another ".

any ideas?

Comment: if(preg_match("/<?php/", $_POST['code']) == true){
 $errors[] = 'You must close your PHP tags';
    
    } <!--something like this ?-->